# SSL issue on Homebrew installation

Tags: ssl, terminal, homebrew, osx-yosemite

When I try to install `Homebrew` using terminal it fails with following error:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/': Could not resolve host: github.com
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n --depth=1
```

I assumed it is because of proxy setting. So I tried to reset git proxy using:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

and

```
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
```

but failed again.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the proxy for git with

```
git config --global --add http.proxy proxyHost:proxyPort
```

but you have also to set the proxy for Homebrew itself with :

```
export ALL_PROXY=proxyHost:proxyPort
```